# java read method returns -1 at the end of file

Tags: java

I am learning about java IO. In the `read()` method there is a notice that said

> it returns -1 at the end of  file

I don't know what this means?
and what is the importance of -1 to be at the end of the file

example:

```
import java.io.*;  
class Simple{  
 public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{  
  FileReader fr=new FileReader("abc.txt");  
  int i;  
  while((i=fr.read())!=-1)  
  System.out.println((char)i);  

  fr.close();  
 }  
}
```

Comment: the value -1 isn't special in and of itself. What's special is that there is a second guarantee - that nothing besides the end of a file will ever result in a -1 from read(). This makes the value -1 a unique response and lets you know exactly when the end of file is reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the docs first!

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#read()

Relevant Section:

> public int read()
>            throws IOException Reads a single character.
>
> Overrides: read in class Reader
>
> Returns: The character read, **or -1 if the end of the stream has been
>   reached**
>
> Throws: IOException - If an I/O error occurs

For what it's worth, these are often referred to as *sentinel values*. Sentinel values are used to indicate some special condition via a return value that is an obvious invalid response (example: -1 since that is obviously not a character). Think of it like a status or error code. In this case, it means status: end of file.

Answer (score 1):

`-1` simply means that **there is nothing more to read** allowing to stop reading the stream before getting an `IOException`.

Answer (score 0):

-1 is when the end of the file has been reached.